# calculate mean for multiple columns in data.frame

Tags: r

Just wondering whether it is possible to calculate means for multiple columns by just using the mean function

e.g.

```
mean(iris[,1])
```

is possible but not

```
mean(iris[,1:4])
```

tried:

```
mean(iris[,c(1:4)])
```

got this error message:

> Warning message: In mean.default(iris[, 1:4]) :   argument is not
>   numeric or logical: returning NA

I know I can just use
    lapply(iris[,1:4],mean)
or
    sapply(iris[,1:4],mean)

Comment: How about `colMeans(iris[,1:4])`. Taking the mean of a data.frame has been deprecated. I'm not sure why you expect that to work when you already know about the `sapply/lapply` solutions.

Comment: Use `?colMeans` or an `apply` approach but maybe for such  a question the best would be a search to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `colMeans`:

But the column must be numeric. You can add a test for it for larger datasets.

```
colMeans(iris[sapply(iris, is.numeric)])
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
    5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333
```

**Benchmark**

Seems long for `dplyr` and `data.table`. Perhaps someone can replicate the findings for veracity.

```
microbenchmark(
  plafort = colMeans(big.df[sapply(big.df, is.numeric)]),
  Carlos  = colMeans(Filter(is.numeric, big.df)),
  Cdtable = big.dt[, lapply(.SD, mean)],
  Cdplyr  = big.df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
  )
#Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq       max
# plafort  9.862934 10.506778 12.07027 10.699616 11.16404  31.23927
#  Carlos  9.215143  9.557987 11.30063  9.843197 10.21821  65.21379
# Cdtable 57.157250 64.866996 78.72452 67.633433 87.52451 264.60453
#  Cdplyr 62.933293 67.853312 81.77382 71.296555 91.44994 182.36578
```

**Data**

```
m <- matrix(1:1e6, 1000)
m2 <- matrix(rep('a', 1000), ncol=1)
big.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(m2, m), stringsAsFactors=F)
big.df[,-1] <- lapply(big.df[,-1], as.numeric)
big.dt <- as.data.table(big.df)
```

Comment: Thank you, I stayed with the lapply too long with it returning lists.

Comment: @user20650 `colMeans(Filter(is.numeric,iris))`

Comment: @CarlosCinelli; nice .. i never seem to use this and  Negate etc etc. looking at Filter it is just unlist(lapply(..)), but more succunct again

Comment: @user20650 it seems a bit faster too.

Answer (score 8):

With `sapply` + `Filter`:

```
sapply(Filter(is.numeric, iris), mean)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
    5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333
```

With  `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1:     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333      NA
```

PS: in `dplyr` you can now use `summarize_if`,

```r
iris %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333
```

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
iris <- data.table(iris)
iris[,lapply(.SD, mean)]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1:     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333      NA
```

Comment: Perhaps `iris %>% summarise_each(funs(mean), -Species)`

Comment: With dplyr, "funs(mean)" is depricated, should use instead "list(mean=mean)"

Answer (score 0):

Your above solution does work assuming the columns are in the correct is.numeric format. See below example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
mean(a)

b <- c(2,4,6)
mean(b)

d <- c(3,6,9)

mydata <- cbind(b,a,d)


mean(mydata[,1:3])
```

Comment: This isnt quite right . The above example is a `data.frame` and there is not a method for using mean on a data.frame. Your example (sort of) works as you can take the mean of a `matrix` (`class(mydata)`): but it gives an overall mean rather than by column.