# Mean vector of iris dataset by columns

Tags: r, rstudio, mean

I want a mean vector of the iris dataset such that the first element in the vector is the mean of the first column, the second is the mean of the second column etc..

My code is:

```
data("iris")

mean(iris[,1:4])
```

I get the message:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(iris[, 1:4]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

If I try to calculate the mean of each collumn with mean(iris[,1]), mean(iris[,2])... I have no problem but if I do the mean(iris[,1:4]) it returns NA

Comment: `sapply(iris[,1:4], mean)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the \*apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family)

Comment: Answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941504/calculate-mean-for-multiple-columns-in-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `colMeans` to get the mean values for each column/list (a data.frame is a set of lists). `mean` only works on single vectors.

```
colMeans(iris[,1:4])
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
    5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333
```